# Why my content is showing below my Appbar?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, appbar

I'm trying to add an AppBarLayout that, when there is no need to scroll (or content has not been scrolled), the elavation is 0, but when the user can scroll or have scrolled, then the elavation is shown (like Google Tasks app). In the [new material Appbar documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/app-bar-layout/) I found that adding the `app:liftOnScroll="true"` property to my Appbar will do the trick, but after adding that the content of my NestedScrollView shows above the toolbar:

[image]

The other problem I'm facing is, even if I don't use `app:liftOnScroll="true"` is that my NestedScrollView is not showing at the bottom of the Appbar:
[image]

This is my Fragment's xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ResetPasswordFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar_resetPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_resetPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Some Content -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know that if I add `layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to my NestedScrollView the problem will be kind of solved, but I've seen a lot of examples where they create the view that I want without adding that.

This is the style I'm using for my activity

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/barlow</item>
    </style>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` works with Coordinatorlayout .. Wrap your layout inside a `Coordinatorlayout`

Comment: How can I be so dumb -_- ! All the time I was thinking I was using CoordinatorLayout... thanks a lot

Comment: You can answer the question and I'll mark your response if you want @ADM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` works with `CordinatorLayout` . So you need to use `CordinatorLayout` as parent instead if `ConstraintLayout`..